# How to center slideshow elements in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, carousel

I'm building a slideshow, like [Swiper.js](https://swiperjs.com/) but I'm having trouble getting the active element centered in the container, I managed to get it more or less working but there are two issues:

1. It only works when the `activeSlide` is incrementing
2. It's not a very elegant solution

```js
import React, { FC, useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Carousel: FC = () => {
  const [activeSlide, setActiveSlide] = useState(0);
  const slides = Array.from({ length: 6 }, (_, index) => ({
    data: `Slide ${index + 1}`
  }));
  const [translate, setTranslate] = useState(0);
  const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const wrapperRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const slideRefs = useRef<HTMLDivElement[]>([]);

  const initTranslate = () => {
    if (
      containerRef.current &&
      wrapperRef.current &&
      slideRefs.current.length > 0
    ) {
      const slideWidth = slideRefs.current[0].offsetWidth;
      const wrapperWidth = wrapperRef.current?.offsetWidth;

      //translate so slide is centered  in container
      const translateCenter = wrapperWidth / 2 - slideWidth / 2;
      setTranslate(translateCenter);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useeffect");
    if (activeSlide === 0) {
      initTranslate();
    } else if (containerRef.current) {
      //get gap between slides
      const gap = parseFloat(
        getComputedStyle(containerRef.current)
          .getPropertyValue("gap")
          .replace("px", "")
      );
      setTranslate(
        (prev) => prev - (slideRefs.current[activeSlide - 1].offsetWidth + gap)
      );
    }
  }, [activeSlide]);

  const isLeftEnabled = activeSlide !== 0;
  const isRightEnabled = activeSlide !== slides.length - 1;

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center w-3/5">
      <div
        ref={wrapperRef}
        className="w-full overflow-hidden carousel-container"
      >
        <div
          ref={containerRef}
          className="flex gap-10 w-screen mb-8"
          style={{
            transform: `translateX(${translate}px)`
          }}
        >
          {slides.map((slide, index) => (
            <div
              className={`slide ${
                activeSlide === index ? "bg-purple-500" : "bg-green-400"
              } rounded-2xl h-52 w-40 flex place-items-center
    select-none`}
              key={`slide-${index}`}
              ref={(el) => {
                if (el) {
                  return (slideRefs.current[index] = el);
                }
                return null;
              }}
            >
              <p className="m-auto">{slide.data}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="flex gap-6">
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            if (isLeftEnabled) setActiveSlide(activeSlide - 1);
          }}
          className={`rounded-full w-20 h-20 ${
            isLeftEnabled ? "bg-green-600" : "bg-gray-300"
          }`}
        >
          &#9664;
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            if (isRightEnabled) setActiveSlide(activeSlide + 1);
          }}
          className={`rounded-full w-20 h-20 ${
            isRightEnabled ? "bg-green-600" : "bg-gray-300"
          }`}
        >
          &#9654;
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Carousel;
```

I got a working demo here : https://codesandbox.io/s/carousel-scroll-problem-9solvt?file=/src/Carousel.tsx:0-3055

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to maintain a track whether you are going forward or backward, simplest solution would be to create a `previousSlide` variable, using which, you can identify the direction.

I've modified your carousel.tsx file below:

```
import React, { FC, useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Carousel: FC = () => {
const [activeSlide, setActiveSlide] = useState(0);
const [previousSlide, setPreviousSlide] = useState(0);
const slides = Array.from({ length: 6 }, (_, index) => ({
    data: `Slide ${index + 1}`
  }));
  const [translate, setTranslate] = useState(0);
  const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const wrapperRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const slideRefs = useRef<HTMLDivElement[]>([]);

  const initTranslate = () => {
    if (
      containerRef.current &&
      wrapperRef.current &&
      slideRefs.current.length > 0
    ) {
      const slideWidth = slideRefs.current[0].offsetWidth;
      const wrapperWidth = wrapperRef.current?.offsetWidth;

      //translate so slide is centered  in container
      const translateCenter = wrapperWidth / 2 - slideWidth / 2;
      setTranslate(translateCenter);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useeffect");
    if (activeSlide === 0) {
      initTranslate();
    } else if (containerRef.current) {
      //get gap between slides
      const gap = parseFloat(
        getComputedStyle(containerRef.current)
          .getPropertyValue("gap")
          .replace("px", "")
      );
      setTranslate(
        previousSlide < activeSlide
        ? (prev) => prev - (slideRefs.current[activeSlide - 1].offsetWidth + gap)
        : (prev) => prev + (slideRefs.current[activeSlide - 1].offsetWidth + gap)
      );
    }
  }, [activeSlide]);

  const isLeftEnabled = activeSlide !== 0;
  const isRightEnabled = activeSlide !== slides.length - 1;

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center w-3/5">
      <div
        ref={wrapperRef}
        className="w-full overflow-hidden carousel-container"
      >
        <div
          ref={containerRef}
          className="flex gap-10 w-screen mb-8"
          style={{
            transform: `translateX(${translate}px)`
          }}
        >
          {slides.map((slide, index) => (
            <div
              className={`slide ${
                activeSlide === index ? "bg-purple-500" : "bg-green-400"
              } rounded-2xl h-52 w-40 flex place-items-center
    select-none`}
              key={`slide-${index}`}
              ref={(el) => {
                if (el) {
                  return (slideRefs.current[index] = el);
                }
                return null;
              }}
            >
              <p className="m-auto">{slide.data}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="flex gap-6">
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            if (isLeftEnabled) {
              setPreviousSlide(activeSlide)
              setActiveSlide(activeSlide - 1);
            }
          }}
          className={`rounded-full w-20 h-20 ${
            isLeftEnabled ? "bg-green-600" : "bg-gray-300"
          }`}
        >
          &#9664;
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            if (isRightEnabled) {
              setPreviousSlide(activeSlide)
              setActiveSlide(activeSlide + 1);
            }
          }}
          className={`rounded-full w-20 h-20 ${
            isRightEnabled ? "bg-green-600" : "bg-gray-300"
          }`}
        >
          &#9654;
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Carousel;
```